# First inserted record in a oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do we know the first inserted record in table, let consider we have loaded 1 million records into a table and we don't have any time stamp columns here. 
How to find it?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to find this out.

Comment: _Why_ do you need this information?  What are you attempting to do?

Comment: You can insert many records in a single, atomic, transaction. What does it mean for a record to be inserted "first"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no column that indicate order of insert like timestamp, serial fields (ex: primary key) you have no method to find what was the first inserted row. SQL standard says clearly that data sets are not ordered (there is no "natural" order). All hacks like rownum, row id etc. are not warranted to work after reindexing database, reload database and similar operations.

Comment: Although, depending on application design, the row with the "first" id might not be the first row _committed_, anyways...

Comment: You are right - deciding what "first row" means is a problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% accurate (as **piotrpo** pointed out), but if you are ok with accuracy of the value provided by  `ORA_ROWSCN` ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm#BABFAFIC)), you can find out which row was inserted first (surely, if it wasn't updated later) . To be correct, not even row, but the block where row resides - you can use `DBMS_ROWID` functions to drill down to row level (again, not 100% precise) :

```
SELECT  DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_ROW_NUMBER(ROWID),
SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) 
FROM table1 ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 ASC
```

Comment: I just ran a test and this didn't work for me on Oracle 10G. As you said it is not precise. I have a sequence column in my table, so I know which row was inserted first.

Comment: @abhi Sequences didn't guarantee exact order because of caching. Also think about rollbacks, concurrency and so on.

Comment: @a1ex07 Thanks..I learnt new thing here. So as per our discussion, I think we can't find the exact record which was inserted first.

Answer (score 0):

If you had identifying column with ids you anyway couldn't know which row was first, because you don't know if someone manual added row with id lower then rest, one solution is to add to table field with timestamp/date format where you insert time for each row inserted or modified. but...

`SELECT 
  SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn),ora_rowscn
FROM 
  your_table`

you can find when your row was modified/added... maybe there is some solution but not with rowid. with this you can find only first/last updated row...

Answer (score -1):

Just use rowid like

Select * from my_table where rowid in 
(
    Select min(rowid) from my_table
)

it should work

Comment: I don't think rowid works for my requirement. rowid generates based on inserted record? what if it changed in future?